# Can I use AutoIt mouseMove() in a server in the Cloud?

Tags: windows, autoit, remote-server, windows-server

Is it possible to use AutoIt mouse movements in a remote, cloud-based Windows server?

Comment: You could use Autoit locally on your client. With your application which controls the reomte session or you could install Autoit on the server in the cloud and use it directly on the server. (as a program or service)

Comment: So for the first suggestion, you're talking about Windows Remote for example and i would let it run opened? But it defeats the purpose, in my case, of using a cloud server, i want Autoit to work continuously without anything logged in. For the ladder, are you talikng about a real barebone server that i would use as a distant PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you really mean.

If you mean you want a compiled script to run on a remote server even when you're not logged in, you can do that. You just need to write the script and test it from the server, and then compile it to a .exe file, and then set up a Windows scheduled task on the server to run that .exe file whenever you need it to run.

If you mean that you want to run a script from your local machine that does stuff on the server, you can't do that, unless you tell your script to include the steps of logging into the server each time. AutoIt is a GUI automation tool; it can't remotely access another computer on its own, unless you tell it to do so via the UI you have access to on your local machine (or rather, the machine where the .exe script is run).

Comment: i'd like to do the first option. I didn't know if graphic stuff like mouse movements had to have a screen turned on attached to it or not. thanks